# delete rows without loosing the formula in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an excel sheet in which there is one table with a drop down and one normal excel cell. I try to clear the contents of the table and I have done it through

```
range("X").ClearContents
```

but the problem with it is it is going to clearing the content but I'm able to see the table borders with it.

When I have used

```
Range("X").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Range("X").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

It deletes the table (both content and borders) but it I can see the formula in the drop down is missing ie the drop down cell has become normal cell.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Look up [**`Borders`** property of `Range` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822605.aspx) and set it to like `Range("yourNamedRange").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone`. When you are using `Selection.Delete` you are literally deleting everything in the selected area along with formulas and formatting - probably something you want to avoid assuming you want to keep the formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ClearFormats()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196576.aspx), this will remove the table border.

Also, to clear contents, you do not have to first select the range. Take an advantage of the [`With` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

```
With Range("X")
    .ClearContents
    .ClearFormats
End With
```

The above should achieve what you're after.

Comment: Good stuff ++ Iturner